# Copy file from file storage to blob storage using python

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to copy an image from file storage to blob storage using python but unable to get it to work. I have based it on this node.js example [Copy Azure File Share to Blob with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66775509/copy-azure-file-share-to-blob-with-node-js).  The exception I get when running the python code locally is shown below.

> azure.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundError: This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this resource type.

Here is a snippet of the python code.

```
sas_token = generate_account_sas(
    account_name=account_name,
    account_key=account_key,
    resource_types=ResourceTypes(service=True),
    permission=AccountSasPermissions(read=True),
    expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1)
)


blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=blob_uri, credential=account_key)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("event")


share_directory_client = ShareDirectoryClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=conn_string, 
                                                        share_name="test-share",
                                                        directory_path="")
dir_list = list(share_directory_client.list_directories_and_files())
logging.info(f"list directories and files : {dir_list}")

for item in dir_list:
    if item['is_directory']:
        pass
    else:
        fileClient = share_directory_client.get_file_client(item['name'])
        source_url = fileClient.url + "?" + sas_token
        logging.info(f"{source_url}")    
        container_client.get_blob_client(item['name']).start_copy_from_url(source_url)
```

The source url created using the SAS token is shown below.

```
https://<STORAGE_NAME>.file.core.windows.net/test-share/test.jpg?se=2021-10-01T05%3A46%3A22Z&sp=r&sv=2020-10-02&ss=f&srt=s&sig=<signature>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because of incorrect resource type in your SAS token (`srt` value).

Since your code is copying files to blob storage, you need to have `object` as allowed resource type. Please see this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file-share/azure.storage.fileshare.resourcetypes?view=azure-python) to learn more about resource types.

Your code would look something like:

```
sas_token = generate_account_sas(
    account_name=account_name,
    account_key=account_key,
    resource_types=ResourceTypes(object=True),
    permission=AccountSasPermissions(read=True),
    expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1)
)
```

Your SAS URL should look something like:

```
https://<STORAGE_NAME>.file.core.windows.net/test-share/test.jpg?se=2021-10-01T05%3A46%3A22Z&sp=r&sv=2020-10-02&ss=f&srt=o&sig=<signature>
```